# Effeciency Project Euler #1

Tags: java, programming-challenge

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>   Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Could someone point out if there is something wrong with the code; where I should optimize/modify it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumBelowN {

    private double getSum(int N) {
        int n1 = 3;
        int next_n1 = 3;
        int n2 = 5;
        int next_n2 = 5;
        double sum = 0;

        while (next_n1 < N || next_n2 < N) {
            if (next_n1 == next_n2) {
                sum += next_n1;
                next_n1 += n1;
                next_n2 += n2;
                continue;
            } else if (next_n1 < next_n2) {
                sum += next_n1;
                next_n1 += n1;
                continue;
            } else {
                sum += next_n2;
                next_n2 += n2;
                continue;
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i = sc.nextInt();

        // print the sum of all the numbers below 'i'
        // which are divisible by both 3 and 5.
        SumBelowN sumBelowN = new SumBelowN();

        System.out.println("Sum: " + sumBelowN.getSum(i));
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see [Project Euler #1 efficiency](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67103/project-euler-1-efficiency)? It is about the same problem and also about Java. It was already pointed out in the answers to that question that the solution can be computed in O(1), i.e. without any loop, which would be the most efficient method.

Comment: @MartinR I went through the above solution and I can say that it is way better. Thanks for pointing it out. Had I posted this on StackOverflow I would have been downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you did read about the solution that runs in constant time, but wanted to add your own non-constant solution.

**continue**

Your `continue` statements are unnecessary; you can just remove them.

**Naming**

Your naming violates every standard for Java. Java uses [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms) and doesn't allow names to start with uppercase letters.

It is also generally discouraged to use numbers in names if they can be avoided, which in this case they can: `n1` could be called `three`, and `n2` could be `five`. If you want to stay flexible, use `firstMultiple` and `secondMultiple` or something similarly expressive.

**Constants**

As `n1` and `n2` are constants, I would declare them as static fields.

**Comments**

As your solution is not straightforward, I would add a comment or two about how it works.

**Efficiency**

In case you're interested, here are the results that I get if I compare your solution with the solutions from the other thread (mentioned in the comments):

```
name                       per call (mean, ns)     per call (median, ns)     95th percentile (ns)     total (ms)     runs
three loops                280                     277                       256                      0.224          1000000
without function calls     392                     392                       362                      0.3136         1000000
getSum                     694                     695                       641                      0.5552         1000000
with function calls        3739                    3766                      3338                     2.9912         1000000
```

Comment: Yes, the `continue` statements are unnecessary. Also, could you post a demo of how to use your Timing class. I tried reading it, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @yadav_vi I included an example in my first post of the [timing class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64267/generic-timing-class).